# shopify remix app , styles not loading on saving changes in project files

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, remix.run, hot-reload, polaris

I'm encountering an issue with my Shopify app development environment where CSS styles are not reloading properly during hot reload. Whenever I make changes to CSS files and save them in my code editor, the styles disappear and I need to manually reload the app to see the changes. This behavior is causing inconvenience and slowing down the development process.

I'm looking for guidance on how to troubleshoot and fix this issue with CSS not reloading and styles disappearing during hot reload in my Shopify app development environment. Any insights, suggestions, or known solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is missing any debugging details. Please check out [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Chrome, try opening your app in an Incognito window to see if the styles reload with HMR.

I had the same problem, and it turned out I had a Chrome Extension installed that was interfering with the Remix hydration.